# Displaying image from referenced entity in a view

Tags: views, entities

I am trying to create an image albums with the biblio content. These are the steps I have taken:

1. On the Biblio content type, I added a new field called Image of type Image
2. Created a new content called Album. Added one field of type Entity reference; and referenced, to the Biblio content, with multiple selection
3. This is where I'm stuck, creating a view for the albums. I'm not able to display the image content of the biblio entity reference. I have added a relationship to the entity reference: referencing the biblio entity. And added the field Content:Image with a relationship to the biblio entity.

I'm at loss, I know I have a big mistake in the view, but I'm not getting the big picture on how to relate.

[image]

Comment: Hi Hicham, welcome to Drupal Answers. Did you use the correct relationship (i.e., in the right direction)? Could you post screenshots of your View configuration?

Comment: Please check the above view configuration screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're reference relationship is in the wrong direction. Using `Entity Reference: Referenced Entity` as the relationship will provide all fields of the entity (i.e., Biblio content type) that is referenced by your entity reference field (on your Album content type).

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to display the content of "Album" with the contents reference to "Biblio", first in views follow these steps:

1. Select the content type of "Album"
2. Create a relation ship with reference to "Biblio"
3. Then again select an image in fields and enable the relationship with the same (which you have selected in relationship).